# change the name of the downloading file for the user downloading in php or html

Tags: php, html, header

Hi Is there is any way which i can give the user different  name of the file  which i have inside my server

`for example` i have file inside my server which has md5 name like

```
33e65007ba9387583d4902e5497fc9ac.mp3
```

i need when the user click to download this file to change the name of the downloading file to  `something.mp3`

and this  changing wanna be just with the user file downloading  and it will not effect the name of the file in my server

```
More detail :
```

1. name of server file is :`33e65007ba9387583d4902e5497fc9ac.mp3`
2. name of the user file after downloading `something.mp3` with
       out changing server file

how can i do this thing ? with php ?

Comment: Share your code where you are trying to download..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved the problem by changing my download php file to

```
<?php
$file = $_GET['file'];
header ("Content-type: octet/stream");
header ("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=".$file.";");
header("Content-Length: ".filesize($file));
readfile($file);



exit;
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could store file name in $name, and file content in $content. Then, use the following codes to download the file:

```
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header("Content-type: application/force-download");
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $name);
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . strlen($content));
ob_clean();
flush();
echo $content;
```